# How to add a "policy text" just before the comments?

Tags: comment-form

Is there any plugin that can do that?

Answer (score 8):

Hi **@Emerson:**

Do you want before the list of comments or before the comment form *(I assume the latter?)*

If yes, and I'm assuming you are either using the TwentyTen theme or a theme that uses the new `comment_form()` function from WordPress 3.0.0?  If so it's as simple as using the `'comment_form_before'` hook. Here's an example you can place in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
do_action('comment_form_before','my_comment_form_before');
function my_comment_form_before() {
?><p>By leaving a comment you are pledging your first born to my command! Muhahaha! :-)</p><?php
}
```

Comment: Honesty is always the best policy. +1

Comment: This didn't work. I am using the "Graphene" template.  http://www.khairul-syahir.com/wordpress-dev/graphene-theme

Comment: @Emerson - Then Graphene is not using the `comment_form()` function that comes in WordPress 3.0 it would seem. Can you verify?

Comment: I believe do_action should be add_action for this code to work. Just tested and it works. Tried to edit the code but edits must be more than 6 chars.

Answer (score 3):

Just add it in before the comment function (unless I misunderstood something?):

```
<div class="policy">policy text</div>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

This would be on **single.php**, **page.php**

Comment: Wouldn't it be loop.php ?

Comment: Would be outside the loop I'd think, loop serves to display posts.

Answer (score 2):

You may use my plugin [Magic Widgets](https://github.com/toscho/WP-Magic-Widgets). It creates a sidebar (widget) area on four actions. Plus, you get a text widget that outputs exactly the markup you put therein.

There is a second plugin for the comment form. After activation you can place a widget on any place there.

**Screenshot**

[image]

You don’t have to change the theme’s code, and you can even switch themes, and the widgets will stay in place.

Comment: Thank you for making this plugin, it was exactly what I was looking for. I would only ask that you give us, non-german speakers, a fair chance to understand it better. The plugin is in english, but your website is NOT, and your site is the place where we will go to seek for answers before bothering you with our questions. I had to break my head for two hours before realizing how it works, and I am pretty sure you explained it on your site, but out of the five languages I speak, german is not one of them. Imagine others who speak only one? Only English, and via a translator, that doesn't have g